# Disable adding HTML elements to the DIV using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the code

```
<div id="whatever">
/* I have setted up a button to enter html code in this div via jquery*/
/* Now I want to devise another button which will disable further addition addition to the div elements with the previous html as it is*/
</div>
```

How can I do this ? Is there any way apart from jquery(maybe CSS). I tried :

```
$(".whatever").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$(".whatever").prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

Further research and I came to know that only form elements have a disabled attribute.

Comment: div can't be `disabled`. And `.` is for class selector and `#` for id selector .

Comment: why do you want to disable div?

Comment: You can add overlay to the div.

Comment: I am designing a Point of sale system. On clicking on the products(eggs,milk,etc) they get added to the order(the div which I am talking about ). Now when I click backspace button the last item in the list disappears. But after proceeding to the final billing I dont want the backspace to delete further entries. That is the reason I want to disable further editing to the div.
For further details see the link:
http://ge.tt/428aStb1?c

Comment: @tushargupta http://ge.tt/428aStb1?c
P.S. my div consists of ul elements which also cannot be disabled. So setting disabled = true will not help

Comment: @user3530790 see my answer with the working fiddle below

Answer (score 0):

add a class to the div when you click the button that you want to disable `div` with, say `disabled`... and then check for this class in the appropriate piece of code to see if it's present, if so - don't add anything to it...

something along these lines:

```
$('.addButton').click(function(){ 
   if ($('#whatever').hasClass('disabled'))
      return false;
   // your code here
});

$('.disableButton').click(function(){
    $('#whatever').addClass('disabled')
});
```

Here is the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6YnUL/).

By clicking "add html" button it appends html to the div, by clicking "disable" button - it disables the div and you won't be able to add new html to it when you click "add html" button, also I added "enable" button just to show you how you can do it in case you'll need it

Comment: Elegant ! I never thought of this. Stupid of me :P Thanks btw ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a much cleaner way than adding and removing attributes directly.

```
$("div *").disable();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/tnaZV/120/)

Comment: divs cannot be disabled as someone already pointed out.. you can definitely add the attribute to it but that would be improper way of doing it

Comment: I am not disabling div, I am using universal selector * which matches all elements in div and then disable those.

Comment: right, but I was talking about the div that you disabled in your fiddle though... so what I was saying is that what of div had other html elements other than form elements (which are the only ones you can, or want to that is, apply `disabled` to)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'disabled' state for 'div' elements. What you can possibly do is that you can use a boolean variable like 'isEditable' in Javascript and set it to the respective state. For example:

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/weM57/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var isEditable = true;

    $("#btnAdd").click(function() { 
        if (isEditable) {
            $("#whatever").append("<p>this is some content</p>");
        } else {
            $("#status").html("<p>The div is not editable at the moment</p>");
        }   
    });

    $("#btnDisable").click(function() { 
        isEditable = false;
        $("#status").html("<p>The div is not editable anymore</p>");
    });

    $("#btnEnable").click(function() {  
        isEditable = true;
        $("#status").html("<p>The div is editable now</p>");
    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Content" />

    <hr />

    <input type="button" id="btnDisable" value="Disable Content Adding" />
    <input type="button" id="btnEnable" value="Enable Content Adding" />

    <hr />

    <div id="whatever">

    </div>

    <div id="status" style="border: dotted 1px gray; background-color: yellow; padding: 20px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: using global vars like this is not a good way of doing things in JS and eventually can lead to potential problems

Comment: @dima: I am aware of that, the intent here is to give the OP a possible approach / way out. Obviously in a larger application, one would / should not put out global vars like that. But if all I had was this HTML I pasted above, I would happily use a global var, just me :)